# Heuristic 'characterization' of Hausdorff dimension

Tags: soft-question, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

I was wondering whether there is a heuristic simpler way to understand the saying that a *compact* $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies $\dim(E)=\alpha\in (0,d)$? Or maybe saying that $\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}(E)\in (0,\infty)$, where $\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-Hausdorff outer measure?

For example, if $\lambda(E)=0$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, I would say that "$E$ has $0$ volume". This can also be done in other cases with somewhat complicated definitions. Is there a conceptually simple way to grasp what it means for $E$ to have Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$?

Comment: The $x$-axis $L$ in $\mathbb R^2$ has Hausdorff dimension 1 but $\mathcal H^1(L)$ is infinite.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am aware that $\dim(E)=\alpha$ does not imply that $0<\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}(E)<\infty$. I was wondering if there is some way to visualize in a simpler manner what it means for $E$ to have Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$. Perhaps something with the correct scale or rate at which we look on $E$?
I am also interested in such a description for compact sets.